# How to set fit-content for width in right side - dynamic content width

Tags: css, width, right-to-left

How to set fit-content for width in right side. I used `fit-content` value for width and every things Okay in left side, but in right side content put in center of page. I use this CSS for make dynamic width by content:

```
.chat li.right .chat-body {
    margin-right: 60px;
    border: 1px solid $c-grey;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-color: #e3e3e3;
    /*box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #cfcfcf;*/
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-left: 20%;
    max-width: 80%;
    width: fit-content;
}
```

It's my chat example:
[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/essvision/pen/rWyMKa?editors=0100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace with my give code.

```
.chat li.left .chat-body {
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-color: #e3e3e3;
    /*box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #cfcfcf;*/
    border-radius: 2px;
    /* margin-right: 20%; */
    max-width: 80%;
    width: fit-content;
    float: left;
}

.chat li.right .chat-body {
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-color: #e3e3e3;
    /*box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #cfcfcf;*/
    border-radius: 2px;
    /* margin-left: 20%; */
    max-width: 80%;
    width: fit-content;
    float: right;
}
```

and:

```
.chat li small.pull-left {
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-top: 5px; 
    clear:both;   
}
.chat li small.pull-right {
    padding-right: 60px;
    padding-top: 5px; 
    clear:both;
}
```

[Working Demo](http://codepen.io/essvision/pen/QGpYPy?editors=0100)

Comment: thanks, but time have problem and doesn't in bottom of message

Comment: It's not bottom of text message and it's put in bottom of avatar image.